# why is there a lead (Pb) warning on extra heavy duty batteries?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have some batteries labelled as Extra Heavy Duty with a picture of a trashcan and the letters Pb for lead, and an x over the trashcan which I believe means not to discard in the trash.  The batteries also say not for retail sale, so I suspect that they were the original batteries in some children's toys from which I pulled them out.  I found on the web that the likely chemistry is zinc chloride, and I don't see any lead in the chemical reaction.

What is the source of the lead?  Is it just impurities in the zinc, as can occur with zinc-galvanized hardware?  I know that in the galvanization process lead is added to the kettles for metallurgical reasons.  Is there something similar going on here?

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/481556/why-is-there-a-lead-pb-warning-on-extra-heavy-duty-batteries

Answer (score 1):

If the battery has a lead warning on it, its chemistry is lead/lead sulfate and both the plates in the electrolyte and the jumpers between cells are made of lead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Just to clarify, this is a AA battery.  I know that lead sulfate batteries can be recharged, but this is labelled as extra heavy duty and was probably shipped with the children's toy as a single use throw-away (now recycle) battery.  Are you familiar with AA batteries using lead sulfate chemistry?

Comment: No I am not, but size D batteries have been available in lead-acid form for years.